# Can the Weierstraß and/or Kuhn-Tucker theorems be used to obtain and characterize a solution? Why or why not?

Tags: general-topology, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Question: An agent who consumes three commodities has a utility function given by:

$u(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x^{1/3}_1+\min\{ x_2,x_3\}$

Given an income $I$, and prices of $p_1,p_2,p_3$. Describe the consumer’s utility maximization problem. Can the Weierstraß and the Kuhn-Tucker theorems be used to obtain and characterize a solution? Why or why not?

Comment(s): I am unsure on how to set up my Lagrange multiplier function. I know the general function form, but this is a type of problem I have not yet encountered. Moreover, I am unsure of how to set up my constraint. (I am very much used to have a constraint function just given to me) any help is appreciated.

EDIT 1:

$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_1}=-\frac{1}{3}x^{2/3}-\lambda+(\lambda p\cdot x_1)=0$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x_2}= -1-\lambda+\lambda(p_2+p_3)x_2=0$

$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \lambda}=-x_1-x_2+\lambda(p_1x_1+(p_2+p_3)x_2-I)=0$

$p_2=p_3$

$\lambda = 1$

$x_2=1$

Comment: Can you please fix the bug in utility function? There are two $\min$ and the outer $\min$ is useless.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: This question was [crossposted](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/37299/can-the-weierstrass-and-the-kuhn-tucker-theorems-be-used-to-obtain-and-character).

Comment: @Tony456 Please close any one of the questions. I have posted same answer for both.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $x_i$ represents the quantity and belongs to $\mathbb R_{+}$. You can form the constraints as follows:
$$
x_i \geq0 \quad\forall i \in [3] \\
\sum_{i=1}^3p_ix_i \leq I
$$
You can simplify the objective by noting that for the utility to be the maximum, $x_2 =x_3$. Try to reason why this is true. Hence, the final problem becomes,

$$\
\max_{x_1, x_2, x_3}x_1^{1/3} +x_2 \quad s.t. \\
x_i \geq0 \quad\forall i \in [3] \\
\sum_{i=1}^3p_ix_i \leq I \\
x_2=x_3
$$
Can you now set up the lagrange multiplier function? As far as KKT conditions are concerned, I believe they should help because you are trying to maximize a concave function(in $\mathbb R_+$) subject to convex constraints and the strict inequality constraint is linear.

**Edit 1:** Let's eliminate $x_3$ as we know that $x_2=x_3$. The problem simplifies to
$$\
\min_{x_1,\ x_2}\ -x_1^{1/3} -x_2 \quad s.t. \\
x_1 \geq0,\ x_2 \geq 0 \\
p_1x_1 + (p_2 + p_3)x_2 \leq I
$$
$$\
\mathcal L(x_1, x_2)=-x_1^{1/3} -x_2 + \lambda_1(-x_1) + \lambda_2(-x_2) + \lambda(p_1x_1 + (p_2 + p_3)x_2 - I)
$$
**Edit 2:** I see solving the Lagrangian can be tough. Let's simplify, we know that all constraints cannot be active at the same time. It will yield an utility of zero.

**Case-1:** $x_1=0, x_2>0$
You can check algebraically, $x_2=\frac{I}{p_2+p_3}$. Hence, utility$(U)=\frac{I}{p_2+p_3}$

**Case-2:** $x_1>0, x_2=0$
You can check algebraically, $x_1=\frac{I}{p_1}$. Hence, utility$(U)=\left(\frac{I}{p_1}\right)^{1/3}$

**Case-3** $x_1>0, x_2>0$
You can now use the Lagrangian, its much simpler than the original Lagrangian problem because $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0$
$$\
\mathcal L(x_1, x_2)=-x_1^{1/3} -x_2 + \lambda(p_1x_1 + (p_2 + p_3)x_2 - I)\\
\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial x_1} = 0 \implies x_1 = \left(\frac{1}{3\lambda p_1}\right)^{3/2}\\
\frac{\partial\mathcal L}{\partial x_2} = 0 \implies \lambda = \frac{1}{p_2+p_3}\\
\text{Use the constraint, }p_1x_1 + (p_2 + p_3)x_2 = I \text{ to find } x_2
$$
You can simply finish saying the solution is $\max$ of all three cases. As per the KKT conditions are concerned, one of the three solutions will satisfy KKT Conditions depending on $p_1, p_2, p_3 \text{ and } I$. Note that this is no different from the original problem and hence, KKT condition should be satisfied by one of the three depending on $p_1, p_2, p_3 \text{ and } I$. We could have obtained the same solution using the original Lagrangian. Even there we would have ended up with a $\max$ because of $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ and invoking KKT.

Comment: I will try solving the problem and let you know what I garner as a result. As for the KKT how do I prove the quasi concavity? That is something I still don’t get about KKT.

Comment: I have made an edit. I see that the objective is concave. Proving concave is easy right? Just check the hessian. For quasi-concave you can go by the definition or check if the function is monotonic. Checking with multi-variable is tough though.

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I will try this out and see how I do.

Comment: I am still kinda stuck, but I have progressed further with the problem. Please see the above edits. My real concern is solving the complex partial derivatives (always has been a problem for me with these types of problems)

Comment: @Tony456 I hope the final edit answers your question.